# What is the difference between a StackPanel and DockPanel in WPF?

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, dockpanel

What can a `DockPanel` do that a `StackPanel` cannot? If anyone has an image of something that can be achieved with a `StackPanel`, but not a `DockPanel`, than that would be great.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Stack Panel**: The `StackPanel`, as the name implies, arranges content either horizontally or vertically. Vertical is the default, but this can be changed using the `Orientation` property. Content is automatically stretched based on the orientation (see screenshot below), and this can be controlled by changing the `HorizontalAlignment` or `VerticalAlignment` properties.

[image: StackPanel example screenshot]

**Dock Panel**: The `DockPanel` is used to anchor elements to the edges of the container, and is a good choice to set up the overall structure of the application UI. Elements are docked using the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property. The order that elements are docked determines the layout.

[image: DockPanel example screenshot]

Comment: A `StackPanel` will not constrain its children to the available size, whereas a `DockPanel` will size the last child to occupy all remaining space. [stackpanel-dockpanel-and-scrolling-items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2009/06/09/stackpanel-dockpanel-and-scrolling-items.aspx)